# Wear OS - Standalone wear app architecture

Tags: android, wear-os

I am building a standalone Wear OS app which sends sensor data: Hearth sensor data, GPS, Sleep Data to cloud, without Android Phone.
I will develop it on Huawei Watch 2, which has LTE communication.
I have two problems:

1. I do not have Experience in Android Development. I read that it's not possible to make a direct call from Watch to Web Server using LTE.
2. It is possible to develop an app collecting all sensor informations? Hearth Rate, Fitness Data, GPS and Sleep Data?

Would you please recommend some courses or instructions that are helpful to me ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as usual the official documentation is a good starting point. Here are some links to get started with what you are looking for:

- Sample basic app: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps
- Create and run a wearable app: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating
- Network access and sync on Wear OS: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access
- And this demo project to access the sensors on the watch: https://github.com/google/wear-sensors